# Select specific columns, where the column names are in another df in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I couldn't find a solution in stack, so here's my issue:

- I have a df with 342 columns.
- I want to make a new df with only specific columns
- The list of columns to keep is in another df, listed in 3 columns titled X,Y,Z for 3 new dataframes

Here's my code right now:

```
# Read the data:
data <- data.table::fread("data_30_9.csv")


# Import variable names #
variable.names.full = openxlsx::read.xlsx("variables2.xlsx")
Y.variable.names = na.omit(variable.names.full[1])
X.variable.names = na.omit(variable.names.full[2])
Z.variable.names = na.omit(variable.names.full[3])

# Make new DF with only specific columns:
X.Data = data %>% select(as.character(X.variable.names)) # This works as X has only 1 variable
Y.Data = data %>% select(as.character(Y.variable.names)) # This give an error: Error: 
#                                                        # Can't subset columns that don't exist.
```

Help?

the data is available here:

1. https://github.com/amirnakar/TammyA/blob/main/data_30_9.csv
2. https://github.com/amirnakar/TammyA/blob/main/Variables2.xlsx

Comment: So at the end you want to end up with 3 dataframes?

Comment: Yes, with 3 dataframes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Y.variable.names` is a `data.frame` which you cannot use to subset another `data.frame`.

You can check by typing `class(Y.variable.names)`.

So the solution to your problem is subsetting `Y.variable.names`:

```
Y.Data = data %>% select(Y.variable.names[,1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `lapply` on `variable.names.full` and select the columns from `data`.

```
list_data <- lapply(variable.names.full, function(x) 
                    data[, na.omit(x), drop = FALSE])
```